# How to create Bootstrap panel based on JSON output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to generate `Bootstrap` panel based on `JSON` output.
here is my sample `JSON` output

```
$valMS = '[
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "rooter",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "binu",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "cal",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "nera",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }
]';
```

here is I tried `JQUERY` function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('<div class="container" ></div><br>');

    var html = '<div class="container" ><div class="panel panel-default">';
    html += '';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $valMS; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+index+'</div>';
    });
    html += '';
     $.each(data2, function(index, value){
         html += '<div class="panel-body">';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += ''+value2+'';
        });
        html += '</div>';
     });
     html += '</div>';
     $('body').append(html);
     console.log(html);
});
</script>
```

According to my code which generates panel like this

[image]

But I really need this

[image]

What I need to change in my code. How to generate panels for this `JSON` output. Thank you

Comment: As example, do you you want to display: Test, rooter, 12-03-17 in a row?

Comment: @JituRaiyan http://stackoverflow.com/a/43321073/7362095 this answer works fine. but I need to display panel like this image http://i.imgur.com/FJSXA2o.png  3 panels for each row

Comment: ok, I'll modifying this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319262/how-to-create-bootstrap-panel-based-on-json-output/43321073#43321073) answer

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer** and **[Demo which will show 3 panels per row.](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/0rfocmgo/3/)** Reside result window in fiddle to see.
Just change the code inside the **`$.each`** method to get the expected 3 panels per row

```
$.each(valMS, function(index, v){
            if(index % 3 === 0){
          html += '<div class="row">';
        }
        html += '<div class="col-md-4">';
        html += '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        if(index % 3 === 2 || index == (valMS.length - 1)){
          html += '</div>';
        }
     });
```

Above code i used **`col-md-4`** which will 1/3 column in desktop resolution. 
If you want it from all the screens(Mobile also), Replace **`col-md-4`** with **`col-xs-4`** check below code for it - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/0rfocmgo/4/)

```
$.each(valMS, function(index, v){
                if(index % 3 === 0){
              html += '<div class="row">';
            }
            html += '<div class="col-xs-4">';
            html += '<div class="panel panel-default">';
            html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
            html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';
            html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            if(index % 3 === 2 || index == (valMS.length - 1)){
              html += '</div>';
            }
         });
```

I Refactored your code, It is working fine as you asked in question Please check **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/0rfocmgo/)**

```
var valMS = [
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "rooter",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "binu",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "cal",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "nera",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }
],html;

 $(document).ready(function () { 
  html = '<div class="container" >';
    var flag = 0;
    $.each(valMS, function(index, v){
        html += '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
         html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';

        html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
         html += '</div>';
     });
     html += '</div>';
     $('body').append(html);
});



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**[working example Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/0rfocmgo/)**

Comment: @Sai how can I display 3 panel for each row. like this image 
http://i.imgur.com/FJSXA2o.png

Answer (score 2):

Rooter, I just modify @Sai's [How to create Bootstrap panel based on JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319262/how-to-create-bootstrap-panel-based-on-json-output/43321073#43321073) this answer. And this shows 3 panel in each row. Here is the code for that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script>
 var valMS = [
   {
     "Subject": "Test",
     "Message": "rooter",
     "Date": "12-03-17"
   },
   {
     "Subject": "Test",
     "Message": "binu",
     "Date": "12-03-17"
   },
   {
     "Subject": "Test",
     "Message": "cal",
     "Date": "12-03-17"
   },
   {
     "Subject": "Test",
     "Message": "nera",
     "Date": "12-03-17"
   }
 ],html;

  $(document).ready(function () { 
   html = '<div class="container"><div class="row">';
     var flag = 0;
     $.each(valMS, function(index, v){
         html += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-default">';
         html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
          html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';

         html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
          html += '</div></div>';
      });
      html += '</div></div>';
      $('body').append(html);
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jitu. ur a great man :) I'm really happy about u . u helped much more for me today . thanks again :D

Comment: Welcome @Rooter

Comment: @JituRaiyan you should not copy others answer. If your using other answers code then should mentions name

Comment: Your code may brake as you added all the columns in single 'row'. row max columns should be 12 only. i've already updated my answer.Please check. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I mentioned your name in my answer. Your last updated answer is right. But, there is nothing wrong in my answer. If 12 columns are overloaded in a single row then the extra columns goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out  as it will provide expected result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('body').append('<div class="container"></div><br>');

  var html = '<div class="container" >';
  html += '';
  var flag = 0;

  var data2 = [{
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "rooter",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "binu",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "cal",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "nera",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }];

  $.each(data2, function(index, value) {
    var count = 1;
    html += '<div class="panel panel-default col-xs-3" style="padding:0;margin:3%">';
    for (var key in value) {

      if (count % 2 != 0) {
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">' + value[key] + '</div>';
      } else {
        html += '<div class="panel-body">' + value[key] + '</div>';
      }
      count++;
    }
    html += '</div>';
  });
  html += '</div>';
  $('body').append(html);
  console.log(html);
});
</script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how can I display 3 panel for each row. like this image 
http://i.imgur.com/FJSXA2o.png

Comment: updated my answer , col-xs-3 is your answer with margin