# Page content not showing after Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In this JQuery function generate table based on `JSON`  but problem is after this function other content is not showing. I'm trying to add html table after this function. but it's not working properly. why? and how can I solve this.

```js
var data = [{
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com",
    "sac": "sac@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
  html += '<tr>';
  var flag = 0;
  $.each(data[0], function(index, value) {
    html += '<th>' + index + '</th>';
  });
  html += '</tr>';
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    html += '<tr>';
    $.each(value, function(index2, value2) {
      html += '<td>' + value2 + '</td>';
    });
    html += '<tr>';
  });
  html += '</table>';
  $('body').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Updated**

**Sample Footer**

```
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#222;">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <br>
           <br>
           <center><img class="icon" src="images/logo.png" width="291" height="218" alt="logo"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="color:#e0e0e0;">
           <h3 style="margin-top:10%;color:#42a5f5">ABOUT US.</h3>
           <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's<br>
              when an unknown printer took a galley of type and The following<br>
              example shows how to<br><br>
              get a three various-width columns <br>
              make a type specimen book. It has survived not only <br>
              but also the leap into electronic typesetting,<br>
           </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <h3 style="margin-top:7%;color:#42a5f5"><br>NAVIGATION</h3>
           <label style="color:#e0e0e0">
              HOME &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <hr>
           </label>
           <label style="color:#e0e0e0">
              SITE &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <hr>
           </label>
           <label style="color:#e0e0e0">
              ABOUT US &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <hr>
           </label>
           <label style="color:#e0e0e0">CONTACT US &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <h3 style="margin-top:4%;color:#42a5f5"><br>OUR LOCATION</h3>
           <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="250" height="200" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=national school of business management,sri lanka&ie=UTF8&t=hybrid&z=15&iwloc=B&output=embed">
              <div><small><a href="http://embedgooglemaps.com">
                 embedgooglemaps.com
                 embed google map
                 embed google maps
                 google maps karte erstellen
                 </a></small>
              </div>
              <div><small><a href="https://ultimatewebtraffic.com/">buy websit traffic Ultimatewebtraffic</a></small></div>
           </iframe>
        </div>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <p style="color:#29b6f6">Copyright &copy; Green University 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-1x" style="color:#42a5f5"></i>&nbsp;
           <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-1x" style="color:#42a5f5"></i>&nbsp;
           <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-1x" style="color:#42a5f5"></i> &nbsp;
           <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-1x" style="color:#42a5f5"></i> &nbsp;
           <i class="fa fa-delicious fa-1x" style="color:#42a5f5"></i>&nbsp;
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does “it's not work properly” mean? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Creating a snippet shows something does work. Please let us know expected output

Comment: @mplungjan  JQuery function working fine,it's generate table well. but after this JQuery function nothing will be displayed. html table, panel, footer , table etc. not dispalying

Comment: There is a pattern in your questions where you simply are not providing enough details about the specific problems and not providing [mcve]'s

Comment: @PatrickHund JQuery function working fine,it's generate table well. but after this JQuery function nothing will be displayed. how can I display other page contents after this JQuery function ?

Comment: We can't tell you why other parts of page aren't showing properly without being able to see what is there, and what css is used. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Do you want to show the other content (e.g. another table, footer etc) after the table you created by JavaScript?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sure, problem is not  in a css. problem in a JQuery. after this JQuery nothing will show

Comment: Again....you need to provide an example that shows this behavior...we can't guess. Can put demos in any number of different sandbox sites like jsfiddle.net, plnkr.co, codepen etc

Comment: @JituRaiyan yes u are correct :) how can I do this.

Comment: also try `prepend` instead...a footer would be at bottom of body and you are putting table after that. A content container to put this new html into would probably help you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line:

```js
$('body').append(html);
```

you should write:

```js
$(html).insertAfter('.another-section');
```

Then you can append the table after `.another-section` element. (`.another-section` is just an example here). You can append your child at any place of the DOM, not only at the last of the `body`.

Comment: I tried as u said. but when I add $(html).insertAfter('.another-section'); instead of $('body').append(html); , JQuery function not working

Comment: I'm also have another question. how can I display these panel. I mean 3 panel for each row. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43321073/7362095

Comment: Thank u very much :D

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of adding multiple answers.

Answer (score -2):

Move your

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to somewhere above your javascript.

Try this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
var data = [{
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com",
    "sac": "sac@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
  html += '<tr>';
  var flag = 0;
  $.each(data[0], function(index, value) {
    html += '<th>' + index + '</th>';
  });
  html += '</tr>';
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    html += '<tr>';
    $.each(value, function(index2, value2) {
      html += '<td>' + value2 + '</td>';
    });
    html += '<tr>';
  });
  html += '</table>';
  $('body').append(html);
});
    </script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the table wouldn't be being produced if this was the problem. What is shown above is how stack snippets are set up

Comment: what difference would that make?

Comment: Maybe the OP didn't notice there's a "$ is not defined" because jquery.min.js is coming after his actualy jquery calls. It's the only problem I can see in his code.

Comment: but OP has already stated the table works....so `$` has to be defined when their code runs

Comment: Oops, didn't notice OP's comment saying JQuery function is working fine.

Comment: Which table do you see when you run the code? I see both tables, the one with header "Company  Contact    Country" and the table with header "UserID UserName Password Country Email sac".